Possible to gain muscle as an underweight person without bloating your face?
Context:

18 years old
182 cm / 6 feet
62 kg / 137 pounds

I Have been working as a model for the past year which requires me to have defined facial features and being a person that stores a lot of fat in the cheeks area , having a low body fat was the only way to not seem bloated. I've been going to the gym for the past 3 weeks and eating around 2.200 calories daily instead of my "normal" 1.700.  I have since noticed a (not significant) change to my face fat.
Question:  Is there a plan / technique I can follow to gain muscle without gaining fat? Or is this a part of the process? I am willing to get serious about it so I dont mind having a strict diet and workout program.
My current workout plan is as seen in this post .Only difference being that for cardio I run around 50km per weekly.
As of my diet I am trying to eat 2 eggs and some form of meat every day but don't really have a plan that I follow.
Thanks for taking the time to read this .Any help would be appreciated!

Since the answers did not mention it: it is partly genetically and partly phytogenically (gow you grew up, your early childhood) determined where and how fast you gain fat. Thus, there is no general answer to the specific question possible. It may be you can gain some kilos of fat without your face showing much, it's also possible you gain some 100 grams and it shows only in your face. Considering you're underweight and very lean, this is not probable, bit still possible.

As a beginner lifter you should see dramatic strength and size gains without needing to necessarily eat above maintenance intake.
I’m assuming that at 1700 calories you were not gaining or losing weight so assuming this is your true maintenance (it seems really low), you should be able to gain a fair bit of muscle.
Of course, you likely won’t see maximal gains without increasing food intake but, again, as a beginner you will see stark increases in muscle mass.
Also looking at your other post about your routine, it may be worth dialing back the volume a little bit. Since you are untrained and also underweight, your body may struggle to handle large training volumes

You want to gain muscles without gaining fat, AKA the holy grail of bodybuilding. It's not easy but not impossible.
But it's possible to minimize the fat gain with some clever strategies. Make sure your calorie surplus is not too high - for now you're on 500 kcal extra (but you should try to figure out what's your actually maintenance calories to know how much extra are you actually eating, there are plenty calculators online to help you with that).
Try to focus your diet on eating mostly lean protein sources, then some carbs for fuel, and then some fat - you need fat for hormones and other body processes. Also plenty of calculators online for these.
Check your weight weekly; if it's going up you're gaining muscle and fat - how much of which depends on the nutrition an training. Once you feel you gained too much fat just dial down the food a bit for a few weeks until you are comfortable again, then repeat the process. There's no need to do extreme bulks or cuts. Make sure you spend most of your time at maintenance or surplus.
You're 18 and you're training - that is already good. Just keep at it, 4x / week is plenty. Sleep and proper hydration are also important for face bloat - at least to reduce water retention.
